# Can i call a function when If statement fails

Tags: c#, function, if-statement, unity-game-engine

```
void Update()
{
    bool playerInView = false;

    foreach (RaycastHit hit in eyes.hits)
    {
        if (hit.transform && hit.transform.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerInView = true;
        }
    }

    if (playerInView)
    {
        print ("Detected");
    }
    else
    {
        void OnGUI () {
            GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 90), "Loader Menu");
        }
    }
}
```

}

When i run in Unity it says `void` cannot be used in this context
but when i remove function and just call a print then it works

Comment: Please show the actual error message. How is the function called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in this way:

```
bool playerInView = false;

void Update()
{
    playerInView = false;
    foreach (RaycastHit hit in eyes.hits)
    {
        if (hit.transform && hit.transform.tag == "Player")
        {
            playerInView = true;
        }
    }

    if (playerInView)
    {
        print ("Detected");
    }
}




void OnGUI()
{
    if (!playerInView)
    {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 90), "Loader Menu");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: another question plz
where i should use 

"hit.collider.gameObject.name"

to detect a particular game object and show its name on GUI

may be this is very beginner question
but i am beginner in Unity and in C#

Comment: Just add to OnGUI function: GUI.Label( new Rect(...), hit.collider.gameObject.name );

Comment: Unity Runs but when player come in raycast it gives error

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: You have to check if the hit is successful and if the references to collider, gameObject are not null before trying to use them

Answer (score 2):

The part

```
else
{
    void OnGUI () {
        GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 90), "Loader Menu");
    }
}
```

is not valid C# syntax; a function cannot be defined locally in this way. Perhaps you mean

```
else
{
    GUI.Box(new Rect (10, 10, 100, 90), "Loader Menu");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
if (playerInView)
{
    print ("Detected");
}
else
{
    GUI.Box (new Rect (10, 10, 100, 90), "Loader Menu");
}
```

Comment: Thanks to reply bro but 
Unity is giving me error
"You can only call GUI functions from inside OnGUI"

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to write your question in an understandable context.
anyway, you should write it like,

```
void Update()
    {
        bool playerInView = false;

        foreach (RaycastHit hit in eyes.hits)
        {
            if (hit.transform && hit.transform.tag == "Player")
            {
                playerInView = true;
            }
        }

        if (playerInView)
        {
            print("Detected");
        }
        else
        {
            OnGUI();
        }
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        GUI.Box(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 90), "Loader Menu");
    }
```

Comment: Sorry about explanation

Comment: Unity is giving me error
"You can only call GUI functions from inside OnGUI"